# Override make pattern rule for specific folder

Tags: makefile

Take the following example makefile:

```
OUTPUT_DIR := out
FILES += $(wildcard *.txt)
FILES += $(wildcard foo/*.txt)
OUTPUTS := $(patsubst %.txt,$(OUTPUT_DIR)/%.txt,$(FILES))

$(OUTPUT_DIR)/%.txt: %.txt | $(OUTPUT_DIR)
        cp $< $@

#Override for specific folder
$(OUTPUT_DIR)/foo/%.txt: foo/%.txt | $(OUTPUT_DIR) $(OUTPUT_DIR)/foo
        echo "foo" > $@

.PHONY: all
all: $(OUTPUTS)

$(OUTPUT_DIR):
        mkdir $@

$(OUTPUT_DIR)/foo:
        mkdir $@
```

I am attempting to "override" the default pattern rule (for .txt files) if the files are located in the "foo/" subdirectory.  In the example above, my overriding rule does not get executed.  However, if I make this specific to a file as so:

```
$(OUTPUT_DIR)/foo/bar.txt: foo/bar.txt | $(OUTPUT_DIR) $(OUTPUT_DIR)/foo
        echo "foo" > $@
```

the rule does get executed.

So, how can I override the pattern rule for a whole **folder**?

Comment: What version of GNU make are you using?

Comment: @MadScientist GNU Make 3.81 (for Msys)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting with GNU make 3.82 (released 12 years ago), make will resolve pattern rules using a "shortest stem" rule; if multiple patterns match then the pattern with the shortest stem (the most specific match) will win.

Prior to GNU make 3.82, GNU make always went by strict ordering: the first pattern rule that matched was used.

Since you're using a very old version of GNU make (released 16 years ago), you'll have to switch your makefile to use the old form by reversing the order of your rules:

```
# Overrides must appear BEFORE more generic rules
$(OUTPUT_DIR)/foo/%.txt: foo/%.txt | $(OUTPUT_DIR) $(OUTPUT_DIR)/foo
        echo "foo" > $@

$(OUTPUT_DIR)/%.txt: %.txt | $(OUTPUT_DIR)
        cp $< $@
```